# How to create Browse File Button functionality in Android

Tags: android, popup, radio-button

I have a RadioButton that is when clicked, it will bring to a popup window.
Currently, I am planning to make the popup window to contain a browse Button with TextEdit left of it.

What it does is, when a user click on browse Button, a window explorer (something like that) will appear and let the user to traverse the phone's primary/secondary memory. When a file has been selected (clicked twice), the TextEdit will contain the whole directory address for the specified file.

I am not sure how to do this implementation, and I have google it and can't find any answer.
Do you guys by any chance know any tutorial or information about this?

Thank you so much in advance

Comment: What part in particular doesn't work?  What have you tried?